# Targeting Closest Enemy With Joystick

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

My targeting system is not really behaving like I wanted to. The way how I did mine is to first get the local position (as shown in the image below) of the Enemies (green triangle) and filter the list with the x and y axis of the joystick from the selected target (purple circle).

So let's say that I push the stick to the +1 of X-axis, it filters all the Green triangle that has positive X and sort the list by closest distance to the Purple circle (selected target) to get the next target.

Here's a sample of my code for better clarity.

```
// Switching target system
private void SwitchTarget()
{
    // Right stick direction
    float rightXRaw = Input.GetAxisRaw("RightStickX");
    float rightYRaw = Input.GetAxisRaw("RightStickY");

    // List for the enemies
    localTargets = new List<Transform>();

    // Filtering and adding the target based on the right stick direction (Only right, left, up and down)
    foreach (Transform localTarget in targets)
    {
        // Setting the enemies' world coordinate to local coordinate relative to the selected target
        Vector3 localChildPos = selectedTarget.Find("localChild").transform.InverseTransformPoint(localTarget.position);

        if (rightXRaw == 1 && localChildPos.x < 0)
        {
            localTargets.Add(localTarget);
        }

        if (rightXRaw == -1 && localChildPos.x > 0)
        {
            localTargets.Add(localTarget);
        }

        if (rightYRaw == 1 && localChildPos.z < 0 && Mathf.Abs (localChildPos.x) < 3)
        {
            localTargets.Add(localTarget);
        }

        if (rightYRaw == -1 && localChildPos.z > 0 && Mathf.Abs (localChildPos.x) < 3)
        {
            localTargets.Add(localTarget);
        }

    }

    // Sorting the created list based on distance from the selected target, then select the first member from the list.
    SortDistTarget(localTargets);
    SelectTarget();
}
```

It's ok, but at certain occasion it's not selecting what I want since it's only filtering based on 4 direction (e.g. left, right, up and down). So I thought maybe there's a better and more precise method of doing this using the joystick direction directly, with raycast maybe. Would love to hear any alternative to the problem.

Coming back to this method, my questions is, how to get the closest proximity of the Enemy from the casted ray by the joystick direction (which is casted from the purple circle, the selected target)?

[image: Targeting with Joystick]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to calculate the angle for each of the enemies relative to your current position. You can get this by calculating :

Math.Atan(localchildpos.x/localchildpos.y) * 180 / Math.PI

for each of the local targets. You would also need to have the angles for the different joystick directions. The 'closest' enemy in that direction would then be the enemy with the angle closest to the joystick direction (keeping in mind that the an enemy at 355 degrees is only 5 degrees away from joystick direction zero degrees).

I suspect this might still not get you the behaviour you really want. If an enemy is far away but directly inline with the joystick direction then this enemy will be selected over enemies who are much nearer but only very slightly out of line. Let em know if that is the case and I'd be happy to talk you thru a solution.

Comment: Nice thought, using the delta angle between the two vector never crossed my mine. Would be willing to change into this method, if it's any faster.

Anyway, I'm using a solution by a great guy, I guess this is a bit more direct approach, using the cross product as such to find the distance.

`float targetRayDist = Vector3.Cross (selectedTarget.TransformDirection(stickDirection), localTarget.transform.position - selectedTarget.position).sqrMagnitude;`

Comment: At this time it's working better than before. And the way how I select the closest is to make a condition using the dot product of the stick direction and the targets to exclude the targets opposite the stick direction plus another condition using the cross product that only returns less than 1 unit. So only targets that are close to the stick direction vector will be in the list.

Comment: After the condition I sort my filtered target list by distance to the selected target before selecting the next target. This is to ensure I select the closest target before switching to select the next new target with new filtered list.

I can see that I will have some problem when targets are 1 unit apart or closer. Hence wondering and curious about your solution to this, if not would love to hear your thought.

Comment: In essence my approach would be to define some tradeoff between distance from the center and angle relative to the joystick. Something like float targetProximity = 2.4*(angle between joystick and target) + 3.7(distance to target). Target with the lowest number wins. You'll have to play around with the numbers to get something that feels right. The dot product approach is similar but further away targets will get preference over closer targets (if I remember - my vector math is a bit rusty).